# Apache Camel testing webservice authorization 401

Tags: apache-camel, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

I want to test Apache Camel route with jUnit, but unable to set Authorization header for route.

My route looks like

`from("direct:test")
    .process(new LoggingProcessor())
    .to("spring-ws:{{test.domain}}:{{test.port}}/TestChangedSubjects/TestService");`

in JUnit I send body with header like

`template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:test", new StringSource(request), "Authorization", "Basic dnJlcG8ycnBvOlZyZXBvMDk4");`

Result is Unauthorized [401]

```
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:695)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:606)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:506)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:493)
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:483)
at org.apache.camel.component.spring.ws.SpringWebserviceProducer.process(SpringWebserviceProducer.java:89)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:68)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:375)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:343)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:233)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:343)
at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:184)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:124)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:163)
```

Comment: what your  LoggingProcessor do ?. Does it remove headers (something like create new exchange with fresh headers and body)

Comment: LoggingProcessor is there only for loging purpose, also if I remove them, nothing change

Comment: Shouldn't you put the headers in a Map like ```Collections.singletonMap("Authorization", "Basic dnJlcG8ycnBvOlZyZXBvMDk4")``` the method signature for producer template is like that